# Create hub like filter Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, filter

I have a list with some strings. I want to create filter like the people hub(or programs menu) has with filter by first letter. How to create such thing for a list?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `LongListSelector` from the [Silverlight toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888).

There's a great walkthrough at http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/LongListSelector-walkthrough

Comment: Seems nice thing! Will try it later.Thank you!

Comment: Found this one: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api  just what i wanted!